# include header vs include page

Tags: php, post, include, get

I'm currently using `include 'header.php'` and `include 'footer.php'` in every page, and as far as I know that's how most people do it. I thought of a way that I personally thought would be better, however. I thought of making index.php, then in the index include the page. This would both eliminate the need for a footer and eliminate the need for `include` twice in every page. I'm really new to php, however, so I don't know how I would do this. I tried using `POST` and `GET` methods, but it doesn't seem to work. What I want to achieve is including pages in the header using a URL such as http://mysite.com/index.php?page=history and then load history.php. If I need to clarify something, just ask. Sorry if I don't accept an answer right away, I'm really drowsy. I'll get to it when I can.

Comment: Use a [framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/). There's a whole universe of complexity beyond including a header/footer that you're unaware of.

Comment: I want to do everything from scratch so I can change anything later. I just want to know how to do this right now, not have something that does it for me. I won't learn anything from that.

Comment: In fact. it's **three** includes - header, footer, and **page template** itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off i agree with Meager... Take a look at soem frameworks. Most will use a two step view which essentially does this althoug in a more complex and flexible way.

With that said it would look something like this:

```
<?php 
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'home'; // default to home if no page

if(file_exists($page.'.php')) {
  // buffer the output so we can redirect with header() if necessary
  ob_start();
  include($page.'.php');
  $content = ob_get_clean();

}
else
{
  // do something for error 404
}
?>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php echo $content; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could get more complex than that. One thing you want to do uis make sure you dont blindly assume that the page in the `$_GET` var is safe... make sure the file exists on your server or otherwise sanitize it...

Comment: Massive security risk; You're allowing anyone to include _any_ file on the server. You could even get an infinite loop going with `?page=index` that would include itself over and over. Always check input like this against _valid_ options, like an array of available pages, or limit the include to a specific directory (stripping directory separators from the input). You added a remark about this, but I fear your bad code practice may mentally override such warnings for anyone looking at your example.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem if you include 2 pages in a file, like header.php and footer.php...
Just writing 2 lines of code in each page is not a matter.

You can decide what pages you want to include dynamically in every page by using if statement, instead of passing the page name in the url.

Comment: I would strongly prefer the method I mentioned, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll do it via index.php, you will no doubt do it wrong.
Nothing bad - every newbie does it this way.
Just because you're thinking of *includes*, while you should be thinking of **templates**.

You can make it via index.php, no problem. But there should be not a single HTML tag in this index! As well as in the actual page.

No matter if you're doing it in separate pages or via index.php, the scenario should be the same:

1. Get all data necessary to display particular page.
2. Call a template.

Thus, your regular page would look like

```
code
code
code

include 'template.php';
```

while index.php  would look like

```
get page name
sanitize page name
include page
include 'template.php';
```

now you can decide what to choose